# Using Word2Vec embeddings with other continuous data for clustering

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, word2vec, word-embedding

I am preparing data for clustering in R using a variational autoencoder to compress the data before perfoming clustering analysis on it.

My data set has a large amount of continuous data and one freetext field which contains strings of different features as below (300 total entries)

```
Subject_ID<- c("1", "2", "3", "4")
Symptoms <- c("Pain, Fatigue, Tiredness", "Tiredness, Fatigue", "Pain, Rash", "Rash, Fatigue")


# Create a dataframe
df <- data.frame(Subject_ID = Subject_ID, Symptoms= Symptoms)
```

I am trying to create word embeddings for the 7 most common symptoms use with other continuous variables in R using word2vec.

```
Freetext <- df$Symptoms
maxlen = 7

library(keras)

tokenizer <- text_tokenizer(num_words = max_features)
tokenizer$fit_on_texts(Freetext)
sequences <- tokenizer$texts_to_sequences(Freetext)
x_text <- pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen = maxlen)

library(word2vec)

x_text <- as.character(x_text)

model <- word2vec(x = x_text, type = "cbow", dim = 100, window = 5, iter = 10)
embeddings <- as.matrix(model)
```

This creates an output matrix but I am unsure how I can add these embeddings to a data frame alongside other data to cluster each subject.

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Just as a side observation: if you've only got 300 total 'texts' (subjects), most just 1-3 words (symptoms), with a total vocabulary of only 7 uunique words (symptoms),  a 100-dimensional word-vector model is unrealistically oversized for your data. Among other things, you *definitely* don't want to try to use a 100-dimension dense continuous embedding model for something that would fit in a simple sparse 7-dimensional one-hot model. …

Comment: …A dense embedding model makes sense when you've got many, many more unique tokens than dimensions, with plenty of data to learn the subtle many-dimensional relationships between different tokens. If your data is just the presence or absence of 7 symptoms, a word2vec-style dense modeling step is unlikely to add anything of value.